# Can't find a file csv same directory - VsCode/wsl

Tags: python, csv, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I´m tying to read a file called moveis_cp.csv that is in the same directory as python script (I´m absolutelu sure about they are in same folder).

```
import pandas as pd
notas = pd.read_csv("movies_cp.csv")
```

In VSCode with WSL shows the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'movies_cp.csv'
```

I also tried the full path and with "./" , but the problem ramain

This same code worked well in jupyter  notebook

Comment: It's looking for that file in the _current directory_, which is not necessarily the same directory as the python script.

Comment: have you double checked the spelling of the file name and wether it's actually a .csv file? (You misspelled movies in your question btw, maybe that happened with your filename as well? 
You could also try to copy and paste the filename, sometimes one doesn't find the stupidest mistakes...

Comment: it's the same directory, I´ve renamed both from VSCode and checked in the WindowsExplorer

Comment: I did this (copy and paste) @Mi

Comment: The current working directory may not be what you think it is. Try printing `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Yeah @martineau ! I was running the code from a directory above.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For anybody continuing to have this problem. 1) consider providing full path when opening the CSV file. 2) within the full path either replace single '' with a double backslash '\' OR have an 'r' before the file name.

```
notas = pd.read_csv(r'file path')
```

Hope that helps anybody.